# Request the second load of the page with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was happily scrapping property data from www.century21.com with Python `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. There is pagination in the site and I was able to scrap the results of the first page, but when I tried the to do the same for the second page, I got the data of the first page as output.

Here is an example of first page results: http://www.century21.com/real-estate/ada-oh/LCOHADA/#t=0&s=0

And here are the results of the second page for the same search term: http://www.century21.com/real-estate/ada-oh/LCOHADA/#t=0&s=10

I noticed that when I manually click the second URL to open it in the browser, the results of the first URL are showing for few seconds and then the page seems to fully load and show the results of the second page.

As you can imagine, Python `request` is grabbing the results of the first load of the second page which happens to be the same as the results of the first page. Same if I request third page results, fourth and so on.

Below is my code. If you run the it, it will print the address of the first property of the first page twice.

Any idea how to grab the correct page results?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page1=requests.get("http://www.century21.com/real-estate/ada-oh/LCOHADA/#t=0&s=0")
c1=page1.content
soup1=BeautifulSoup(c1,"html.parser").find_all("div",{"class":"propertyRow"})[0].find_all("span",{"class":"propAddressCollapse"})[0].text

page2=requests.get("http://www.century21.com/real-estate/ada-oh/LCOHADA/#t=0&s=10")
c2=page2.content
soup2=BeautifulSoup(c2,"html.parser").find_all("div",{"class":"propertyRow"})[0].find_all("span",{"class":"propAddressCollapse"})[0].text

print(soup1)
print(soup2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make requests to "search.c21" endpoint, get the HTML string from the "list" key and parse it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page1 = requests.get("http://www.century21.com/search.c21?lid=COHADA&t=0&s=0&subView=searchView.AllSubView")
c1 = page1.json()["list"]
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(c1, "html.parser").find_all("div", {"class": "propertyRow"})[0].find_all("span", {
    "class": "propAddressCollapse"})[0].text

page2 = requests.get("http://www.century21.com/search.c21?lid=COHADA&t=0&s=10&subView=searchView.AllSubView")
c2 = page2.json()["list"]
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(c2, "html.parser").find_all("div", {"class": "propertyRow"})[0].find_all("span", {
    "class": "propAddressCollapse"})[0].text

print(soup1)
print(soup2)
```

Prints:

```
5489 Sr 235
202 W Highland Ave
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a question: How did you come up with that URL? Any logic behind it?

Comment: @A.S sure, I've used browser developer tools and inspected the Network tab, observing what request were sent during the page load..